# sharepoint 2019 on premise log reports

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

SharePoint 2019
on-premise configuration
no internet access - closed network-  (I had to build the installer) 
   https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51940.sharepoint-2019-offline-installation-of-prerequisites.aspx)

I need to be able to generate reports on who visits pages and views data.

I turned on all the audit logging options i could find a week ago and the audit log reports work for all instances except "Content Viewing"

If i click on Content Viewing and specify the /Documents location I get a "Sorry Something Went Wrong. This report contains no data" message. Along with a link that does not work due to no internet access.

Site Collection Audit Settings
  Audit Log trimming: no  (at least until i get it working)
  Documents and Items: all checked
  Lists Libraries and Sites: all checked

Central Administrator
  Security: IMPC: Auditing: Available
Central Administrator
   Monitoring: Diagnostic Logging: nothing checked.
   Usage and Health Data Collection: Enabled
       Everything but the following is checked*
           Bandwidth Monitoring
           SQL Exception Usage
           SQL IO Usage
           SQL Latency Usage

- note that i just noticed that Tenant Logging and SimpleLogEvent Usage Data_SPUnifiedAuditEntry were unchecked so i checked them, applied the change, visited some pages and view some docs and the error still occurred.

I am wondering if there is something in Manage Site Features or Site Collection Features that need to be activated or if there is some powershell script i need to run. Any ideas?

Comment: i just found another setting to try in central administrator. I went to the Secure Store service and enabled Audit  and set retention for 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

unsure why this worked when the site settings were already set but i ran the powershell code from https://www.lemonbits.com/2018/09/27/sharepoint-audit-logs/  and was able to generate content view spreadsheets immediately.